# Escaping word character selector in Gatsby GraphQL regex filter

Tags: regex, graphql, graphql-js, gatsby

I am currently using Gatsby to build a documentation site for a component library that I have developed. I have installed the Transformer-Remark plugin which creates javascript objects for each markdown file within my site's structure.

As the site is for documentation, I have a Component detail page which outlines how a component can be used by a consumer and the majority of the content of this page is derived from the README.MD of the corresponding package on NPM.

On the left hand side of this page is a dynamic menu which lists the components I have created. The menu makes use of a GraphQL query within a custom Gatsby template to split the components into 3 categories based on a RegEx filter of their fileAbsolutePath like so:

```js
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    pageData: 
      markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $path } }) {
        html
        fields {
          slug
          title
        }
        fileAbsolutePath
      }


    atoms:
      allMarkdownRemark(sort: {order: ASC, fields: [fields___title]}, limit: 1000, filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/dl-atoms-(\w+)/README/"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }

    molecules:
      allMarkdownRemark(sort: {order: ASC, fields: [fields___title]}, limit: 1000, filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/dl-molecules-(\w+)/README/"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    organisms:
      allMarkdownRemark(sort: {order: ASC, fields: [fields___title]}, limit: 1000, filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/dl-organisms-(\w+)/README/"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
`;
```

However when I try to run Gatsby Develop I get the following error:

**Syntax Error: Invalid character escape sequence: \w.**

I have tried adding a second backslash before the string in question to escape it but this doesn't work.

Is there a special way of escaping certain characters in RegEx filters in GraphQL?

**Edit:**

I should add that the same RegEx works fine on this RegEx testing site:
https://regexr.com/436ep

Comment: It should be `regex: /dl-atoms-(\w+)\/README/`, without double quotes. The backslash must be escaped since it is a regex delimiter char.

Comment: That leads to a different error: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character "/". Do I then need to go through and escape the opening forward slash, etc. I'm pretty sure I copied the syntax from the Gatsby or GraphQL documentation so I was under the impression the quotes are required ?!

Comment: Well, it is strange as it seems `"/dl-molecules-(\\w+)/README/"` should work. Maybe the `README` must match the whole string, try `"/dl-molecules-(\\w+)/.*README.*/"`

Comment: Same error: Syntax Error: Invalid character escape sequence: \w  graphql/template-strings

Answer (score 0):

I think answer for your question is in this thread:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10009

TLDR: create full query in gatsby-node.js and pass it into your template